# Getting an image to display on the same line as my header

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to get my header and image to line up exactly on the same line but am having difficulties. Can anyone see why/suggest a fix?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header img {
  position: relative;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}
#header h1 {
  color: white;
    float: left;
  background-color:#006890;
  font: 75px arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
  <img src="2000px-Smiley.svg.png" alt="Smiley Face" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because of the h1 default margin, you see? elements comes with default styling and you need to custom it to your needs, generally for what you want you need to remove the `margin-top` from h1 but you can also set it to `margin: 0;` if you dont need the `margin-bottom`.

```
#header h1
{
    color: white;
    float: left;
    background-color:#006890;
    font: 75px arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/L2e1rL6L/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to #header h1 css you should do

```
#header h1 {
 margin:0;
}
```

thats it.

Answer (score -2):

Wouldn't you need to have the image inside the `<h1><img > </h1>` tags?

Comment: Thanks guys.  Corp firewall went down while I was trying to edit.